# Symfony 3 Filesystem Component

Tags: php, symfony, filesystems, symfony-3.3

I'm pretty new to PHP and Symfony and I just don't seem to use the Filesystem Component right.
I've followed the offical documentation, found under:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/using_components.html
and tried to install it, but I just dont get where I'm supposed to write the code to.

The docs say:

Once Composer has downloaded the component(s), all you need to do is include the vendor/autoload.php file that was generated by Composer. This file takes care of autoloading all of the libraries so that you can use them immediately:

```
// File example: src/script.php

// update this to the path to the "vendor/"
// directory, relative to this file
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

$finder = new Finder();
$finder->in('../data/');

// ...
```

but where do I have to change this line?
in the vendor/autoload.php? Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Change what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Symfony framework, you don't need to install this component. It's altready included in `symfony/symfony` and is already registered.

You can simply use it like:

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

$finder = new Finder();
```

See this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html)